# Converted SCN file (from DAE file) does not show up in sceneView

Tags: ios11, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, xcode9-beta

I downloaded a `DAE` Collada file from [here](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/f3e4f5b9275fc12bfae0b63d13275cac/Velociraptor) and I opened in the latest `Xcode beta` and converted it to a `SCN` file.

I load the scene object using this method (where `modelName` = `model`, `fileExtension` = `scn`):

```
private func loadModel() {
    guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "\(modelName).\(fileExtension)", inDirectory: "art.scnassets/\(modelName)") else {
        return
    }           
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
            
    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }      
    self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
}
```

However, nothing shows up! The dinosaur only shows ups when I load the `dae` file (by changing `fileExtension` = `dae`), but that dinosaur flickers really weirdly.

And I don't understand why this is not working since if Apple has provided a conversion from `dae` to `scn` in `Xcode` I feel that it should be pretty easy to use the resulting `scn` file.

Any help would be appreciated!

### Code

**Dinosaur.swift**

```
class Dinosaur: VirtualObject {
    
    override init() {
        super.init(modelName: "model", fileExtension: "scn", title: "Dinosaur")
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

**VirtualObject.swift**

```
class VirtualObject: SCNNode {
    
    var modelName: String = ""
    var fileExtension: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.name = "Virtual object root node"
    }
    
    init(modelName: String, fileExtension: String, title: String) {
        super.init()
        self.name = "Virtual object root node"
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.fileExtension = fileExtension
        self.title = title
        
        loadModel()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func loadModel() {
        guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "\(modelName).\(fileExtension)", inDirectory: "art.scnassets/\(modelName)") else {
            return
        }
        
        let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
        
        for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
        }          
        self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
    }

    private func unloadModel() {
        for child in self.childNodes {
            child.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var newObject: VirtualObject = Dinosaur()

@IBAction func loadAd(_ sender: UIButton) {
    newObject.removeFromParentNode()
    newObject.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)   
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newObject)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My solution: Drag the .dae-file into the projects and convert it by the 'duplicate' button.
After I did so, the .scn file appeared and was visible.